# BodyPix person segmentation not working as desired on Nodejs

Tags: tensorflow.js, bodypix

I used the bodyPix model using script tag to import the libraries from CDN as described in the documentation. This works quickly and fine.
But when I am trying to use it on node.js using npm installation, it's taking a long time to segment and takes up all the CPU. I am not finding a solution anywhere.[This is my code-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtQeR.png)

Comment: Can you post your code in your question rather than linking to an image. It would be much easier to debug if it is in text form.

Comment: I actually got that the backend is running on cpu which is the reason behind the bad performance. Tensorflowjs documentation also ensures that the cpu backend won't perform better. Thanks, @user1239299 for your willingness to help.